# JQuery Mobile native select not working on droid

Tags: jquery, android, css, mobile, jquery-mobile

This is absolutely driving me crazy. I have the Droid X 2.3.3. For some reason the native select menus will not open when `data-role="none"` or `"data-native-menu="true"` are set. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper-div">
            <div data-role="page" data-theme="b"> 
                <div data-position="inline" data-role="header">                
                    <h1>Test Page</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="content" data-role="content">               
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="some-options">Some Options:</label>
                            <select data-native-menu="true" name="some-options" id="some-options">
                                <option value="1">Option 1</option>    
                                <option value="2">Option 2</option>      
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="mote-options">More Options:</label>
                            <select data-role="none" name="more-options" id="more-options">
                                <option value="1">Option 1</option>    
                                <option value="2">Option 2</option>      
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="evenmore-options">Even More Options:</label>
                            <select name="more-options" id="evenmore-options">
                                <option value="1">Option 1</option>    
                                <option value="2">Option 2</option>      
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've experienced the same thing. You need to keep the `data-type="page"` directly under `<body>`. See this jQM-issuefor more details: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1051

So, remove the `<div id="wrapper-div">` - you don't need it anyway ;-) However, I believe that jQM shouldn't put these kinds of restraints on us developers. After all, it does work on an iPhone, so I'm quite curious to why it doesn't work properly on Android.

Comment: +1 You sir are a life saver! This helped me. Seems like still they have this problem.

Comment: They could have mentioned this in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

From what i know there's no need to use `data-role="none"`

simply set `data-native-menu="true"` will do.

```
 <select data-native-menu="true" name="some-options" id="some-options">
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>    
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>      
 </select>
```

Sample [here](http://jsbin.com/etece6/2)

Comment: I'm having the same behavior with the link you provided. The menu is not opening.

Comment: i do not own an android but i've tried it on the emulator running 2.3.3 and it works for me. Maybe you wanan try using 1.0a4 instead of a3?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and changing to data-native-menu=false helped, because I don't have SELECT element inside FORM element.

If I understand properly, you should set data-native-menu=true, if you have SELECT inside FORM, based on discussion here:

[JQuery Mobile Select Box not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138321/jquery-mobile-select-box-not-working)